# Quick question regarding notational clarification needed for a question on showing a polynomial ring is a module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

For the following question:

Show that if $V$ is a vector space over a field $F$ then the set $T$ of linear transformations $f:V\rightarrow V$ is a unitary associative $F-$algebra.  If $F[X]$ denotes the ring of polynomials over $F$ and $\alpha$ is a fixed element of $T$, show that $V$ can be made into an $F[X]$ module by the action $F[X]\times V\rightarrow V$ defined by $(p,x)\mapsto p\cdot_{\alpha}x=[p(\alpha)](x).$

Let $T=\{f|V\rightarrow V\}$ be a set of linear transformation from $V$ to $V$ and let $\alpha \in T$.

Do I interpret the notation: "$p\cdot_{\alpha}x$" in $p\cdot_{\alpha}x=[p(\alpha)](x)$ as sort of an evaluation map for polynomials as: $p_{\alpha}\cdot (x)=p(\alpha)(x)$.  So if $p(x)\in F[x],$ and $p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}x^{i}$, then for $\alpha(v)$ being some linear transformation from $V$ to $V$, plugging it into $p$, we have $p(\alpha)(v)=(\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}(\alpha)^{i})(v)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}(\alpha(v))^{i},$ and $a(v)^{i}$ means composition $\alpha(v)$ with itself $i$ times.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Instead of "sort of an evaluation map" it seems better to say that $p\cdot x$ denotes a *module action* (check the axioms that this is indeed a module action!). Of course, the "dot" depends on evaluating $p$ at $\alpha$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde so it is an evaluation map as you also a reading it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde also the book did not have introduce the notation $\cdot_{\alpha}$, I was really confused about what that could have meant.

Comment: An R-module $M$ is an abelian group $M$ together with an action $r\cdot m=r\cdot_{\alpha} m$ such that certain axioms hold. The $\alpha$ here is only a "help" to you in the visibility of such an $\alpha$. But I am sure every book in this area says what an $R$-module is.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I should mention the way i understood it is that i need to plug in a linear transformation, like the way is usually done in linear algebra when it comes to the minimal polynomial. But the notation was really confusing, since other books use the evaluation notation.  If i may ask, how did you make sense of it so fast?

Comment: Dear Seth, "so fast" is relative. The problem you have is very popular, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1270388/question-about-the-k-module-cdot-varphi-kx-times-v-to-v?rq=1), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3109696/turning-the-ring-of-polynomials-mathbbf-lambda-into-a-module?rq=1) or similar posts. So I know this problem since several years already (it will come up again soon here).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I did not know such a notation exists.  I thought the author which is Thomas Blyth, made it up just for the occasion of his text.  Thank you for  pointing it out.

Comment: You are welcome.