# Writing an explicit map and making a vector space defined over field $F$ into a $F[x ,y]$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Example *10.3.13* ($F[x]$-modules). Let $F$ be a field and let $R$ be the polynomial ring $R = F[x]$.
> We propose to determine what left $F[x]$-modules may be. Let $M$ be a left $F[x]$-module.
>
> First note that $F$ (as a subring of $F[x]$) must act on $M$ according to the left $R$-module axioms. Thus $M$ is a vector space over the field $F$. Now consider the action of the element $x$ on $M$. The axioms for a left-module show that the element $x$ behaves as a linear transformation $T$ on the $F$-vector space $M$. Furthermore, the axioms impose no further restrictions on the linear transformation $T$ we use for $x$. Now for any polynomial $p(x) = a_d x^d + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0 \in F[x]$ and for any $v \in M$,
>
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> P(x) \cdot v 
> &= (a_d x^d + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0) \cdot v \\
> &= a_d \overbrace{T(T \cdots T}^{\text{$d$ times}}(v) \cdots )) + \cdots + a_1 T(v) + a_0 v.
> \end{aligned}
> $$
>
> Consequently, an $F[x]$-module consists of two data: an $F$-vector space $V$ and a linear transformation $T : V \to V$. The above equation gives teh action of any polynomial on a vector in $V$.

I have a questions from an exercise which is from the book [*Abstract Algebra Structures and Applications* pg 495](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Abstract_Algebra/jRUqCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=abstract+algebra+structures+and+applications&printsec=frontcover). The question reads as follows:

> Let $F$ be a field and consider the polynomial ring $F[x,y]$.
>
> (a)  Prove that an $F[x,y]$-module consists of vector space $V$ over $F$ along with commuting linear transformation $T_1$ and $T_2$.
>
> (b) Explicitly describe the action of a polynomial $p(x,y)$ on a vector in $V$

Can I get some clarification on what the first question is asking as well, what the difference between the first and second question are?  Is it asking me to show that $V$ as a vector space acted on by the polynomial ring $F[x,y]$ can be make into a module?

As for making the vector space $V$ over $F[x,y]$ into a module, don't I need to worry about the dimension of $V$ since I will need evaluation maps to do so. I included a screenshot of how the author of the text does it in an example for the case of making a vector space $V$ into a $F[x]$ module. I think for the exercise question, the author expects me to give an explicit mapping. So if I disregard the issue of dimension and just attempt a solution like the way the author has done in the included image, I would apply $F[X]$ acting on $V$ and then apply $[y]$ acting on the action of the action of $F[x]$ on $V$.  In mathematical notation, it would be as follows:

Given a vector space $V$, polynomial rings $F[x]$ and $F[x,y]$.  Let $v\in V$, $\alpha_{i}\in F[x]$ with $\alpha_{i}=\sum_{r_{i}=0}^{i}a_{{r_{i}}{i}}x^{r_{i}}$, define the action of $F[x]$ on the vector space $V$ over $F$ by:$\alpha_{i}\cdot_{T_{1}}v=\alpha_{i}(T_{1})v=\sum_{r_{i}=0}^{i}(a_{{r_{i}}{i}}{T_{1}}^{r_{i}})v=\sum_{r_{i}=0}^{i}a_{{r_{i}}{i}}{T_{1}}^{r_{i}}(v).$

Again let $v\in V$, $p\in F[x,y]$ with $p=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\alpha_{i}y^{i}$ and $\alpha_{i}\in F[x]$, then the action of $F[x,y]$ on $V$ can be defined by:
$p\cdot_{T_{2}}v=p(T_{2})(v)=\sum_{{i}=0}^{n} (\alpha_{i}{T_{2}}^{i})v= \sum_{{i}=0}^{n} (\alpha_{i}{T_{2}}^{i}(v))=\sum_{{i}=0}^{n}(\sum_{r_{i}=0}^{i}a_{{r_{i}}{i}}{T_{1}}^{r_{i}}(v)){T_{2}}^{i}(v)=\sum_{{i}=0}^{n}\sum_{r_{i}=0}^{i}a_{{r_{i}}{i}}{T_{1}}^{r_{i}}(v){T_{2}}^{i}(v)=\sum_{{i}=0}^{n}\sum_{r_{i}=0}^{i}a_{{r_{i}}{i}}({T_{1}}^{r_{i}}{T_{2}}^{i})(v)$ 
with ${T_{1}}^{r_{i}}{T_{2}}^{i}={T_{2}}^{r_{i}}{T_{1}}^{i}$ and ${T_{k}}^{p}$ to mean $T_{k}$ composed with itself $p-$times, for $k=1,2$

Can someone look over my work to see if the explicit map I constructed or any of the notations I used for describing how the polynomials rings action on vector space $V$ are correct and which parts of (a) and (b) have I answered, and the parts I have not given an adequate answer, what is it I still need to or have not shown in order to answer the question.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've edited your post to use mathjax (which is searchable) rather than an image (which isn't) so that future users with similar questions have an easier time finding this ^_^. In the future you should do the same

Comment: @HallaSurvivor did you typed out the example in the image, or was there are easy way i can just convert the text from image into mathjax?  If you did the former, omg, thank you so much for all the work.  I did not typed out the image example because i thought I am not suppose to included images where the question that is being asked originates from.  Also, if i typed out, it would make my post to read like some math novella.

Comment: I typed it out. I'm a fairly fast typist, and write a lot of latex, so it doesn't actually take me that long ^_^. And you should include any details that are relevant to your question! Don't feel bad if it makes your question long, and feel free to say exactly where you got your question! Anything that provides context is good. If you're worried about your post becoming too long, using blockquotes `>` and horizontal line breaks `---` is a good way to separate out parts of your question so that people can quickly tell the context, from examples, from your attempts, from your question, etc.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor ah, okay okay, thank you for the tips.  I have a hard time remembering latex syntax, probably because at my uni, math students are never made to learn latex for assignments.  So most of us have to learn it only when we absolutely have to.

Comment: @ThePointer thank you for editing help.  It seems like everytime I ask anything on this site, my brain can't keep what I have learned as far as math typing is concerned from my previous times asking math questions on this site.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have the right flavor of idea, though honestly your notation is so condense that it's hard to read exactly what you're saying. I'll give some hints as to what you should do, and hopefully you can tell me if this is what you've already been doing :P

First, you ask for the difference between parts (a) and (b). They're definitely related, and I think the best thing to do is to try and understand what $F[x,y]$-modules *are*. Then you'll get an answer to parts (a) and (b) at roughly the same time. After all, they're asking for two different *aspects* of the characterization of $F[x,y]$-modules.

Recall from your example $10.3.13$ that an $F[x]$-module is really a vector space $V$ plus a linear map $T : V \to V$. Part (a) is asking you to show that an $F[x,y]$-module is really a vector space $V$ plus *two* linear maps $T_1$ and $T_2 : V \to V$. But they can't be any old linear maps! They must commute. That is, $T_1 T_2 v = T_2 T_1 v$ for every $v \in V$. It's worth thinking about why this is.

Also recall from the same example that we get a computation rule from the above characterization. That is, if you give me a vector space $V$ and a linear map $T : V \to V$, then I know what $p(x) \cdot v$ is! Indeed, if we take a concrete example, say, $x^2 - 3x + 1$. Then

$$(x^2 - 3x + 1) \cdot v = T^2 v - 3Tv + v$$

what we do for other polynomials is hopefully obvious from this example and the discussion in your example.

Part (b) is asking for a similar computation rule for $F[x,y]$-modules. That is, if $T_1$ and $T_2 : V \to V$ and you give me a polynomial $p(x,y)$, say, $x^2 + xy + 3y + 2$, what is $(x^2 + xy + 3y + 2) \cdot v$? Now, in the example you had a polynomial in *one* variable and *one* linear map $T$. Now we have a polynomial in *two* variables and *two* linear maps $T_1$ and $T_2$.... Can you guess what the computation rule should be? I'll include this particular example under the fold if you need a hint:

> $$(x^2 + xy + 3y + 2) \cdot v = T_1^2 v + T_1 T_2 v + 3 T_2 v + 2v$$

Now with this in mind it might be clearer we we need to know that $T_1 T_2 = T_2 T_1$. After all, we know that in $F[x,y]$ we have $xy = yx$... Can you use this equation, plus the axioms for modules, to show that if $T_1$ and $T_2$ are linear maps making $(V, T_1, T_2)$ a $F[x,y]$-module, then we *must* have $T_1 T_2 = T_2 T_1$?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: I was trying to build up a two variables polynomial from one variable polynomial, I got the idea from the book:  An introduction to Algebraic Structures by Joseph Landin:

Comment: "Let $A$ be a ring with unity elements an d let $x$ be an indeterminate over $A$.  Then $A[x]$ is again a ring with unity element, and by the following theorem which states:
>For each (commutative) ring $A$ with unity element, $1,$ there exists an indeterminate $t$ over $A$;
There exists an indeterminate $y$ over $A[x]$.  We shall set $A[x,y]=A[x][y];$ the elements of $A[x,y]$ are polynomials....

Comment: ...$p=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\alpha_{i}y^{i}$
where each $\alpha_{i}\in A[x]$, $0\leq i\leq n,$  hence $\alpha_{i}=\sum_{r_{i}=0}^{i}a_{{r_{i}}{i}}x^{r_{i}},$$0\leq i\leq n,$ Consequently if $p\in A[x,y], then$<br/>
$\sum_{i_{2}=0}^{n_{2}}\sum_{i_{1}=0}^{n_{1}} a_{i_{1}i_{2}}x^{i_{1}}y^{i_{2}}$
where $n_{1},$ and $n_{2}$ are nonnegative integers and the $a_{{r_{i}}{i}}$ are elements in $A$.

Comment: after writing out an explicit action map for the $F[x]$ module over vector space $V$ defined over field $F$ which means the map $\alpha_{i}:F[x]\times V\rightarrow V$ is an action of the polynomial ring $F[x]$ acting on $V$ defined by $\alpha_{i}\cdot_{T_1}x=\alpha_{T_{1}}(x)$.  After this, I need defined another map similar to $F[x]\times V\rightarrow V$ but this time, it is $p:F[x,y]\times V\rightarrow V$. This is where I am not sure $p's$  domain and codomain are written correctly.  $\alpha_{i}$  is supposed to be a homomorphism, and $\alpha_{i}\in Hom(F[x]\times V, V)$...

Comment: so should $p$ be a map which goes from $Hom(F[x]\times V, V)\times V)\rightarrow V$ which is equivalent to the map $F[x,y]\times V\rightarrow V.$   Actually, I don't know how to show $(Hom(F[x]\times V, V)\times V)=F[x,y]\times V.$ I know if i follow the textbook example, I can probably do something like $P(x,y) \cdot v=P_{T_{1}T_{2}}(x,y)(v)$ where $T_{1},T){2}$ are linear transformations from $V\rightarrow V$

Comment: as for the notation "$\cdot_\alpha$, I recently asked a question on notational clarification from Thomas Blyth's textbook on module theory here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4339712/quick-question-regarding-notational-clarification-needed-for-a-question-on-showi.  I know that I need to use something along the line of polynomial evaluation map to make everything explicit and I was really hoping using evaluation maps won't make the notation too...

Comment: ...dense for reading.  I probably should have stated in my original post that was what that notation means.  My apologizes for the confusion.

Comment: at the end of the fifth comment up, there should be a close quote at the end of $a_{{r_{i}}{i}}$ are elements in $A$.  Also, the quoted theorem reads:  'For each (commutative) ring $$ with unity element, $1,$ there exists an indeterminate $$ over $$.'